# Firebase copy data

Tags: angular, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have this collection

```
tags:
-- [tag item]
   -- tagName [string]
   -- postsIds [array]
```

and this collection

```
posts:
  -- postId [string]
  -- content [string]
```

In my frontend users create/update their posts and add tags to them, and I want those tags to just be there to help me sort the posts into the correct array.

I want to do that without having to do that in the client so technically any user has rights to write into the tags collection, is there a safer way to do this? Maybe in the backend?

Comment: Yes, in the backend.

Comment: @DougStevenson do you mind giving me a hint, on how it would be done?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  If you haven't tried anything yet, then Stack Overflow might not be the right place to ask.  There are other forums designed for conversation when you don't have a specific programming question.

Comment: @DougStevenson I guess I haven't tried, because I have not found for something that I understand and can use, I am still in the process of learning Firebase. Maybe what I need is a feature I don't know exists. I'll look somewhere else. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You may consider reversing your data model and keep `tagIds` on a post. A tag might have billions of posts, but a post might only have a few tags. This will scale better:

```
tags:
  -- [tagId string]
posts:
  -- postId [string]
  -- tagIds [array]
```

Then your query would look like `db.collection('posts').where('tagIds', 'array-contains', someTagId)`.